# Why is the blur event firing repeatedly? Sometimes you can't close the alert window

Tags: javascript, events, alert

I bind the `blur` event to the `showAlert` function in the element `table`. When the cursor leaves the `input`, the `blur` event occurs and the `showAlert` function runs and pops up an `alert` window.

Sometimes the `alert` window can't be closed. You close it, then it pops up again, and you close it, and it still pops up. I drew this conclusion after testing the below webpage with Chrome at least 50 times. This problem doesn't occur every time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>goods1</td>
        <td><input type='text' name="goods1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>goods2</td>
        <td><input type='text' name="goods2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<script>
ob = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]
function showAlert(event) {
    ob = event.target;
    alert(ob.tagName);
}
ob.addEventListener("blur", showAlert, true);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please test several times until the problem happens.

[Video of the problem with Chrome](https://www.dropbox.com/s/szmezpiqpawyf6h/test.avi?dl=0)

I get the same problem in Firefox.

[Screenshot of the problem with Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxFgd.png)

If you don't check the "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" box, just click OK, the `alert` window will pop up repeatedly, forever.

What causes this, and how can I make this code more robust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert msg is difficult to work with because it freezes the browser until you click it to close, which requires that you move the mouse, and . . . together with blur, which fires when you leave the element (which happens when you click the alert box...) - it's a bad combination.

Recommendation: create a simple DIV with `position:fixed; top:0; left:25%;` and inject your message into the HTML for that div, and wait for user to click anywhere on page to close it. Use this to replace the alert function and you will be much happier.

A quick demo using jQuery (apologies for using jQuery but I haven't time to translate it - this is just an example not code to solve your problem)

```js
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
  var mymsg = "<i>Here is a sample message. Click on <b>me</b> to close.</i>";
  $('#msg').html(mymsg);
  $('#msg').show();
});

$('#nuther').click(function(){
  var mymsg = "<div id='nuth'>Here is another message. Click on <b>me</b> to close.</div>";
  $('#msg').html(mymsg);
  $('#msg').show();
});

$('#msg').click(function(){
  $('#msg').hide();
});
```

```css
#msg{position:fixed;top:10%;left:25%;padding:10px;text-align:center;}
#msg{font-size:1.3rem;background:bisque;z-index:2;display:none;}

#nuth{color:dodgerblue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg"></div>
<button id="mybutt">Click me</button>
<button id="nuther">Nuther button</button>
```