# Why is my jQuery rows.on("blur", handler) calling handler() in an infinite loop (apparently)

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery 3.6.1. My code is:

```
OSH.setDivisions = function() {
    let rows = $("input[name^='compdiv']");
    rows.on("blur", OSH.doDivisions)
}

OSH.doDivisions = function() {
    alert("In doDivisions()");
    if (OSH.emptyDivisions() == 0) {
        OSH.addDivision();
    }
}
```

When the page loads, nothing happens, as expected. Then if I focus on an input element with a name attribute beginning 'compdiv' and then take away the focus (either by tabbing or clicking), the alert pops up, as expected; but when I dismiss the alert, it pops up again, as many times as I'm willing to dismiss it. Nothing else in the code calls OSH.doDivisions(), and there are no triggers coded.

In case it matters, my page has a form with a table of text input fields. The table is statically coded in html with one row containing three text input fields like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td><input id="compdiv_name[]" name="compdiv_name[]" type="text" style="width:320px"/></td>
        <td><input id="compdiv_adult[]" name="compdiv_adult[]" type="text"  style="width:60px"/></td>
        <td><input id="compdiv_jr[]" name="compdiv_jr[]" type="text"  style="width:60px"/></td>
    </tr>
```

So all three input fields have empty values.

The idea is that when focus leaves one of the fields, OSH.doDivisions() is fired to call OSH.emptyDivisions(), which in turn counts the number of rows that contain 3 input fields with empty values. And if there are no rows with 3 empty values, OSH.addDivision() is called to add another row. Something that I'm sure is a common pattern.

But I can't figure out why this is not working, with doDivisions called repeatedly, even though I am not touching the form.

*** UPDATE ***: Here is the code of the other functions, OSH.emptyDivisisons(), which [zer00ne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2813224/zer00ne) suspects of being the culprit, as well as OSH.addDivision(), which it calls, as well as the $(document.ready() call at the bottom:

```
    OSH.emptyDivisions = function() {
    let numempty = 0;
    let values = [];
    let rows = $("input[name^='compdiv']");
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
        if (rows[i].type != "text") {
            continue;
        }
        if (rows[i].name == "compdiv_name[]") {
            values[i] = rows[i].value;
            if (rows[i + 1].name == "compdiv_adult[]") {
                values[i] += rows[i + 1].value;
                if (rows[i + 2].name == "compdiv_jr[]") {
                    values[i] += rows[i + 2].value;
                    if (values[i] == "") {
                        ++numempty;
                        i += 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return numempty;
}

OSH.addDivision = function() {
    let data = '\
        <tr>\
            <td><input id="compdiv_name[]" name="compdiv_name[]" type="text" style="width:320px"/></td>\
            <td><input id="compdiv_adult[]" name="compdiv_adult[]" type="text"  style="width:60px"/></td>\
            <td><input id="compdiv_jr[]" name="compdiv_jr[]" type="text"  style="width:60px"/></td>\
        </tr>\
    ';
    $("#lastDivision").before(data);
}

$(document).ready(OSH.setDivisions());
```

Comment: I suspect `.emptyDivisions()` but can't say for sure since the code in OP is very small and uninformative .

Answer (score 0):

After tiring of dismissing the `alert(In doDivisions())`, I changed it to `console.log("In doDivisions());` And low and behold it no longer looped! So my conclusion is that dismissing an alert triggers a blur event on any/all(?) visible input elements on the page.

Actually, I see that my question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53164400/why-is-the-blur-event-firing-repeatedly-sometimes-you-cant-close-the-alert-win)